# How to prevent floated parent with floated children from being expanded to 100% width in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-float

I've got a left floated div with 2 rows of left floated child blocks. Each row is cleared with a simple clear block.

Problem is that IE6 expands parent block's width to 100% of available space while in other browsers parent's width is set to exactly wrap the children.

When all child blocks are floated, the width is correct in IE6. But I need children blocks to be arranged in rows, so I put an additional clear block after each row. After that parent's width expands to 100%.

Is there a workaround to have normal parent's block width in IE6? (tables are not welcome)

**[Have a look at the image illustrating the problem](http://tinypic.com/r/mc5gzs/5)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        #parent {
            float: left;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .block {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin: 10px;     
            float: left;
        }

        .clear {
            height: 1px;
            clear: both;
            font-size: 1px;
            line-height: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div class="block">1</div>
        <div class="block">2</div>
        <div class="block">3</div>
        <div class="block">4</div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="block">5</div>
        <div class="block">6</div>
        <div class="block">7</div>
        <div class="block">8</div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to IE6, so I can't actually check this. But you could try the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/YA7CN/

(putting the blocks in a container with clear:both)

As I said, it might give you the same problem... but it's an option. 
By the way, are you designing for a specific public that uses ie6? If not, I wouldn't be too worried about things looking different in it, you will get mad adapting everything to a version that crashes everything it touches!